# Does $f_n (x) = \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converge uniformly on $x \in [0,1]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Full problem statement:

> Show $f_n=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}, \ (0 \leq x \leq 1)$ converges pointwise
>   on  $[0,1]$.
>
> If $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$, is there  $N \in$
>   $\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \lt \frac{1}{4}, \ (n \geq N)$ for
>   all $x \in [0,1]$ simultaneously?

I was able to prove $f_n$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ where,

$f(x) = 0$ for $0 \leq x \lt 1$

and

$f(x)= 1/2$ for $x=1$.

Now there is a theorem that states that if $f_n(x)$ is continuous for each $n$, and it converges uniformly to $f$, then $f$ must be continuous.

In this case $f$ is not continuous since it's a piecewise function with values $0$ and $1/2$. So the contrapositive statement means that $f_n$ cannot converge to $f$ uniformly.

So for any given $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is no $N$ s.t. $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \lt \epsilon, \ (n \geq N)$ for all $x$ simultaneously.

BUT!

**Case 1** $(x = 1)$

$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |0-0| \lt \frac{1}{4}, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

**Case 2** $(0 \leq x \lt 1)$

$f(x) = 0$

So $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \left| \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} - 0 \right|$
$\leq \left| \frac{x^n}{1} - 0\right| = |x^n| \lt \frac{1}{4}$ for a sufficiently large $n$ since $|x| \lt 1$. So let this index be $N$.

Now putting this all together, if we let $n \geq N$, then both cases are satisfied. So there does exist $N$ that works for 
$\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$  $\ \ \ \forall x$ simultaneously.

So for $\frac{1}{4}$, it works. But notice that this would have worked for any given $\epsilon$.

So clearly I made a mistake but I am not able to pinpoint where.

What is my mistake?

Comment: The $N$ depends on $x$. What, roughly, is $f_n(1 - 1/n)$? And $f_n(1 - 1/n^2)$?

Comment: If we always disregard $x=1$ and assume $x \in [0,1)$ and come up with an $N$, then isn't it the fact that this $N$ would work for any value of $x$ and any given $\epsilon \gt 0$? I am still unable to see how $N$ depends on $x$.

Comment: **If** you can find an $N$ that works for all $x \in [0,1)$, then you have uniform convergence. But you cannot find such an $N$, because $$\lim_{x \to 1} f_n(x) = \frac{1}{2}$$ for every $n$.

Comment: Your mistake is that in choosing $N$ such that $x^N<\frac14$, this $N$ must depend on $x$. Namely, $N>\log 4/\log x$.

Comment: I see it now. It all makes sense now. Thanks!